# Node Deploy Failure: New Azure Site

Tags: node.js, azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to deploy an application to Azure which works fine locally and I'm having a real difficult time figuring out what is wrong.

Can someone possibly help decipher what this means> Below is the Deployment log from Azure:

```
Command: deploy.cmd
Handling node.js deployment.
KuduSync.NET from: 'D:\home\site\repository' to: 'D:\home\site\wwwroot'
Copying file: 'package.json'
Using start-up script server.js from package.json.
Generated web.config.
Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0.
Selected node.js version 5.3.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.1: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
meanjs@0.4.2 D:\home\site\wwwroot
├─┬ acl@0.4.9 
│ ├─┬ mongodb@2.1.3 
│ │ ├── es6-promise@3.0.2 
│ │ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY kerberos@~0.0
│ │ ├─┬ mongodb-core@1.2.31 
│ │ │ └── bson@0.4.20 
│ │ └─┬ readable-stream@1.0.31 
│ │   ├── core-util-is@1.0.2 
│ │   └── string_decoder@0.10.31 
│ └─┬ redis@2.4.2 
│   ├── double-ended-queue@2.1.0-0 
│   └── redis-commands@1.0.2 
├── ansi-regex@2.0.0 
├── async@1.5.2 
├─┬ body-parser@1.14.2 
│ ├── bytes@2.2.0 
│ ├── content-type@1.0.1 
│ ├── debug@2.2.0 
│ ├── depd@1.1.0 
│ ├─┬ http-errors@1.3.1 
│ │ └── statuses@1.2.1 
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.4.13 
│ ├─┬ on-finished@2.3.0 
│ │ └── ee-first@1.1.1 
│ ├── qs@5.2.0 
│ ├─┬ raw-body@2.1.5 
│ │ └── unpipe@1.0.0 
│ └─┬ type-is@1.6.10 
│   ├── media-typer@0.3.0 
│   └── mime-types@2.1.9 
├─┬ cfenv@1.0.3 
│ ├─┬ js-yaml@3.4.6 
│ │ ├─┬ argparse@1.0.3 
│ │ │ └── sprintf-js@1.0.3 
│ │ ├── esprima@2.7.1 
│ │ └── inherit@2.2.2 
│ ├── ports@1.1.0 
│ └── underscore@1.8.3 
├─┬ chalk@1.1.1 
│ ├── escape-string-regexp@1.0.4 
│ ├── has-ansi@2.0.0 
│ ├── strip-ansi@3.0.0 
│ └── supports-color@2.0.0 
├─┬ compression@1.6.0 
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.3.0 
│ │ └── negotiator@0.6.0 
│ ├── bytes@2.1.0 
│ ├─┬ compressible@2.0.6 
│ │ └── mime-db@1.21.0 
│ ├── on-headers@1.0.1 
│ └── vary@1.1.0 
├── connect-flash@0.1.1 
├─┬ connect-mongo@0.8.2 
│ └─┬ mongodb@2.0.55 
│   ├── es6-promise@2.1.1 
│   └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY kerberos@~0.0
├── consolidate@0.13.1 
├─┬ cookie-parser@1.4.0 
│ ├── cookie@0.2.2 
│ └── cookie-signature@1.0.6 
├── crypto@0.0.3 
├─┬ express@4.13.3 
│ ├─┬ accepts@1.2.13 
│ │ └── negotiator@0.5.3 
│ ├── content-disposition@0.5.0 
│ ├── cookie@0.1.3 
│ ├── depd@1.0.1 
│ ├── escape-html@1.0.2 
│ ├── etag@1.7.0 
│ ├── finalhandler@0.4.0 
│ ├── fresh@0.3.0 
│ ├── merge-descriptors@1.0.0 
│ ├── methods@1.1.1 
│ ├── parseurl@1.3.0 
│ ├── path-to-regexp@0.1.7 
│ ├─┬ proxy-addr@1.0.10 
│ │ ├── forwarded@0.1.0 
│ │ └── ipaddr.js@1.0.5 
│ ├── qs@4.0.0 
│ ├── range-parser@1.0.3 
│ ├─┬ send@0.13.0 
│ │ ├── depd@1.0.1 
│ │ ├── destroy@1.0.3 
│ │ └── mime@1.3.4 
│ ├── serve-static@1.10.0 
│ ├── utils-merge@1.0.0 
│ └── vary@1.0.1 
├─┬ express-session@1.12.1 
│ ├── cookie@0.2.3 
│ ├── crc@3.3.0 
│ └── uid-safe@2.0.0 
├─┬ file-stream-rotator@0.0.6 
│ └── moment@2.3.1 
├─┬ forever@0.14.2 
│ ├─┬ cliff@0.1.10 
│ │ ├── colors@1.0.3 
│ │ └── eyes@0.1.8 
│ ├── colors@0.6.2 
│ ├─┬ flatiron@0.4.3 
│ │ ├─┬ broadway@0.3.6 
│ │ │ ├── cliff@0.1.9 
│ │ │ └─┬ winston@0.8.0 
│ │ │   └── async@0.2.10 
│ │ ├── director@1.2.7 
│ │ ├── optimist@0.6.0 
│ │ └─┬ prompt@0.2.14 
│ │   ├─┬ read@1.0.7 
│ │   │ └── mute-stream@0.0.5 
│ │   └── revalidator@0.1.8 
│ ├─┬ forever-monitor@1.5.2 
│ │ ├── minimatch@1.0.0 
│ │ ├─┬ ps-tree@0.0.3 
│ │ │ └─┬ event-stream@0.5.3 
│ │ │   └── optimist@0.2.8 
│ │ └─┬ watch@0.13.0 
│ │   └── minimist@1.2.0 
│ ├─┬ nconf@0.6.9 
│ │ ├── async@0.2.9 
│ │ ├── ini@1.3.4 
│ │ └── optimist@0.6.0 
│ ├─┬ nssocket@0.5.3 
│ │ └── lazy@1.0.11 
│ ├─┬ optimist@0.6.1 
│ │ ├── minimist@0.0.10 
│ │ └── wordwrap@0.0.3 
│ ├── timespan@2.3.0 
│ ├─┬ utile@0.2.1 
│ │ ├── async@0.2.10 
│ │ ├── deep-equal@1.0.1 
│ │ ├── i@0.3.3 
│ │ ├── ncp@0.4.2 
│ │ └─┬ rimraf@2.5.0 
│ │   └── glob@6.0.4 
│ └─┬ winston@0.8.3 
│   ├── async@0.2.10 
│   ├── cycle@1.0.3 
│   ├── isstream@0.1.2 
│   └── stack-trace@0.0.9 
├── generate-password@1.1.1 
├─┬ glob@5.0.15 
│ ├─┬ inflight@1.0.4 
│ │ └── wrappy@1.0.1 
│ ├── inherits@2.0.1 
│ ├─┬ minimatch@3.0.0 
│ │ └─┬ brace-expansion@1.1.2 
│ │   └── concat-map@0.0.1 
│ ├── once@1.3.3 
│ └── path-is-absolute@1.0.0 
├─┬ grunt@0.4.5 
│ ├── async@0.1.22 
│ ├── coffee-script@1.3.3 
│ ├── dateformat@1.0.2-1.2.3 
│ ├── eventemitter2@0.4.14 
│ ├── exit@0.1.2 
│ ├─┬ findup-sync@0.1.3 
│ │ ├─┬ glob@3.2.11 
│ │ │ └── minimatch@0.3.0 
│ │ └── lodash@2.4.2 
│ ├── getobject@0.1.0 
│ ├─┬ glob@3.1.21 
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@1.2.3 
│ │ └── inherits@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ grunt-legacy-log@0.1.3 
│ │ ├─┬ grunt-legacy-log-utils@0.1.1 
│ │ │ ├── lodash@2.4.2 
│ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3 
│ │ ├── lodash@2.4.2 
│ │ └── underscore.string@2.3.3 
│ ├─┬ grunt-legacy-util@0.2.0 
│ │ ├── async@0.1.22 
│ │ └── lodash@0.9.2 
│ ├── hooker@0.2.3 
│ ├── iconv-lite@0.2.11 
│ ├─┬ js-yaml@2.0.5 
│ │ ├─┬ argparse@0.1.16 
│ │ │ ├── underscore@1.7.0 
│ │ │ └── underscore.string@2.4.0 
│ │ └── esprima@1.0.4 
│ ├── lodash@0.9.2 
│ ├─┬ minimatch@0.2.14 
│ │ ├── lru-cache@2.7.3 
│ │ └── sigmund@1.0.1 
│ ├── nopt@1.0.10 
│ ├── rimraf@2.2.8 
│ ├── underscore.string@2.2.1 
│ └── which@1.0.9 
├─┬ grunt-cli@0.1.13 
│ └─�� resolve@0.3.1 
├─┬ helmet@0.9.1 
│ ├─┬ connect@3.3.5 
│ │ ├─┬ debug@2.1.3 
│ │ │ └── ms@0.7.0 
│ │ └─┬ finalhandler@0.3.4 
│ │   ├── escape-html@1.0.1 
│ │   └─┬ on-finished@2.2.1 
│ │     └── ee-first@1.1.0 
│ ├── depd@1.0.1 
│ ├── dont-sniff-mimetype@0.1.0 
│ ├─┬ frameguard@0.2.2 
│ │ └── lodash.isstring@3.0.1 
│ ├── helmet-crossdomain@0.1.0 
│ ├─┬ helmet-csp@0.2.3 
│ │ ├── camelize@1.0.0 
│ │ ├── core-util-is@1.0.1 
│ │ └── platform@1.3.0 
│ ├── hide-powered-by@0.1.0 
│ ├── hpkp@0.1.0 
│ ├─┬ hsts@0.1.3 
│ │ └── core-util-is@1.0.1 
│ ├── ienoopen@0.1.0 
│ ├── nocache@0.3.0 
│ └── x-xss-protection@0.1.2 
├── jasmine-core@2.4.1 
├── lodash@3.10.1 
├─┬ method-override@2.3.5 
│ └── vary@1.0.1 
├─┬ mocha@1.20.1 
│ ├── commander@2.0.0 
│ ├── diff@1.0.7 
│ ├─┬ glob@3.2.3 
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@2.0.3 
│ │ └── minimatch@0.2.14 
│ ├── growl@1.7.0 
│ ├─┬ jade@0.26.3 
│ │ ├── commander@0.6.1 
│ │ └── mkdirp@0.3.0 
│ └── mkdirp@0.3.5 
├─┬ mongoose@4.2.10 
│ ├── async@0.9.0 
│ ├── bson@0.4.19 
│ ├── hooks-fixed@1.1.0 
│ ├── kareem@1.0.1 
│ ├─┬ mongodb@2.0.49 
│ │ ├── es6-promise@2.1.1 
│ │ ├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY kerberos@~0.0
│ │ └── mongodb-core@1.2.24 
│ ├── mpath@0.1.1 
│ ├── mpromise@0.5.4 
│ ├─┬ mquery@1.6.3 
│ │ └── bluebird@2.9.26 
│ ├── ms@0.7.1 
│ ├── muri@1.0.0 
│ ├── regexp-clone@0.0.1 
│ └── sliced@0.0.5 
├─┬ morgan@1.6.1 
│ └── depd@1.0.1 
├─┬ multer@1.0.6 
│ ├─┬ busboy@0.2.12 
│ │ ├─┬ dicer@0.2.5 
│ │ │ ├── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ │ │ └── streamsearch@0.1.2 
│ │ └── readable-stream@1.1.13 
│ ├─┬ concat-stream@1.5.1 
│ │ ├─┬ readable-stream@2.0.5 
│ │ │ ├── process-nextick-args@1.0.6 
│ │ │ └── util-deprecate@1.0.2 
│ │ └── typedarray@0.0.6 
│ ├─┬ mkdirp@0.5.1 
│ │ └── minimist@0.0.8 
│ ├── object-assign@3.0.0 
│ └── xtend@4.0.1 
├─┬ nodemailer@1.11.0 
│ ├─┬ libmime@1.2.0 
│ │ ├── libbase64@0.1.0 
│ │ └── libqp@1.1.0 
│ ├─┬ mailcomposer@2.1.0 
│ │ └─┬ buildmail@2.0.0 
│ │   └── needle@0.10.0 
│ ├── needle@0.11.0 
│ ├─┬ nodemailer-direct-transport@1.1.0 
│ │ └── smtp-connection@1.3.8 
│ └─┬ nodemailer-smtp-transport@1.1.0 
│   ├── clone@1.0.2 
│   └── nodemailer-wellknown@0.1.7 
├── owasp-password-strength-test@1.3.0 
├─┬ passport@0.2.2 
│ ├── passport-strategy@1.0.0 
│ └── pause@0.0.1 
├─┬ passport-facebook@2.0.0 
│ └─┬ passport-oauth2@1.1.2 
│   ├── oauth@0.9.14 
npm WARN mongodb-core@1.2.24 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.
│   └── uid2@0.0.3 
npm WARN mongodb-core@1.2.31 requires a peer of kerberos@~0.0 but none was installed.
├─┬ passport-github@0.1.5 
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.2.9200
│ ├─┬ passport-oauth@0.1.15 
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\5.3.0\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.5.1\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
│ │ ├── passport@0.1.18 
npm ERR! node v5.3.0
│ │ └── pkginfo@0.2.3 
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.1
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3 
npm ERR! path D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\.staging\wrappy-e5193d35318260dc6219dca3e7bd3562
├─┬ passport-google-oauth@0.2.0 
│ ├── passport-oauth@1.0.0 
npm ERR! code ENOENT
│ └── pkginfo@0.3.1 
npm ERR! errno -4058
├─┬ passport-linkedin@0.1.3 
npm ERR! syscall rename
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3 
 ├── passport-local@1.0.0 
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\.staging\wrappy-e5193d35318260dc6219dca3e7bd3562' -> 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\got\node_modules\duplexify\node_modules\end-of-stream\node_modules\once\node_modules\wrappy'
├─┬ passport-paypal-openidconnect@0.1.1 
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\.staging\wrappy-e5193d35318260dc6219dca3e7bd3562' -> 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\got\node_modules\duplexify\node_modules\end-of-stream\node_modules\once\node_modules\wrappy'
│ ├─┬ passport-openidconnect@0.0.1 
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
│ │ ├── passport@0.1.18 
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
│ │ └── pkginfo@0.2.3 
npm ERR! enoent 
│ └── pkginfo@0.2.3 
├─┬ passport-twitter@1.0.3 
│ ├── passport-oauth1@1.0.1 
│ └─┬ xtraverse@0.1.0 
│   └── xmldom@0.1.19 
 ├─┬ phantomjs@1.9.19 
npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
│ ├─┬ fs-extra@0.23.1 
npm ERR!     D:\home\site\wwwroot\npm-debug.log
│ │ ├── graceful-fs@4.1.2 
│ │ └── jsonfile@2.2.3 
│ ├── kew@0.4.0 
│ ├─┬ md5@2.0.0 
│ │ ├── charenc@0.0.1 
│ │ ├── crypt@0.0.1 
│ │ └── is-buffer@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ npmconf@2.1.1 
│ │ ├─┬ config-chain@1.1.9 
│ │ │ └── proto-list@1.2.4 
│ │ ├── nopt@3.0.6 
│ │ ├─┬ osenv@0.1.3 
│ │ │ ├── os-homedir@1.0.1 
│ │ │ └── os-tmpdir@1.0.1 
│ │ ├── semver@4.3.6 
│ │ └── uid-number@0.0.5 
│ ├── progress@1.1.8 
│ ├─┬ request@2.42.0 
│ │ ├── bl@0.9.4 
│ │ ├── caseless@0.6.0 
│ │ ├── forever-agent@0.5.2 
│ │ ├─┬ form-data@0.1.4 
│ │ │ ├── async@0.9.2 
│ │ │ ├─┬ combined-stream@0.0.7 
│ │ │ │ └── delayed-stream@0.0.5 
│ │ │ └── mime@1.2.11 
│ │ ├─┬ hawk@1.1.1 
│ │ │ ├── boom@0.4.2 
│ │ │ ├── cryptiles@0.2.2 
│ │ │ ├── hoek@0.9.1 
│ │ │ └── sntp@0.2.4 
│ │ ├─┬ http-signature@0.10.1 
│ │ │ └── ctype@0.5.3 
│ │ ├── json-stringify-safe@5.0.1 
│ │ ├── mime-types@1.0.2 
│ │ ├─�� node-uuid@1.4.7 
│ │ ├── oauth-sign@0.4.0 
│ │ ├── qs@1.2.2 
│ │ ├── stringstream@0.0.5 
│ │ ├── tough-cookie@2.2.1 
│ │ └── tunnel-agent@0.4.2 
│ └─┬ request-progress@0.3.1 
│   └── throttleit@0.0.2 
├── semver-utils@1.1.1  extraneous
├── serve-favicon@2.3.0 
├─┬ socket.io@1.4.3 
│ ├─┬ engine.io@1.6.6 
│ │ ├─┬ accepts@1.1.4 
│ │ │ ├─┬ mime-types@2.0.14 
│ │ │ │ └── mime-db@1.12.0 
│ │ │ └── negotiator@0.4.9 
│ │ ├─┬ engine.io-parser@1.2.4 
│ │ │ ├── has-binary@0.1.6 
│ │ │ └── utf8@2.1.0 
│ │ └─┬ ws@1.0.1 
│ │   ├── options@0.0.6 
│ │   └── ultron@1.0.2 
│ ├─┬ has-binary@0.1.7 
│ │ └── isarray@0.0.1 
│ ├─┬ socket.io-adapter@0.4.0 
│ │ └─┬ socket.io-parser@2.2.2 
│ │   ├── debug@0.7.4 
│ │   └── json3@3.2.6 
│ ├─┬ socket.io-client@1.4.3 
│ �� ├── component-bind@1.0.0 
│ │ ├── component-emitter@1.2.0 
│ │ ├─┬ engine.io-client@1.6.6 
│ │ │ ├── component-inherit@0.0.3 
│ │ │ ├── has-cors@1.1.0 
│ │ │ ├── parsejson@0.0.1 
│ │ │ ├── parseqs@0.0.2 
│ │ │ ├── xmlhttprequest-ssl@1.5.1 
│ │ │ └── yeast@0.1.2 
│ │ ├── indexof@0.0.1 
│ │ ├── object-component@0.0.3 
│ │ ├─┬ parseuri@0.0.4 
│ │ │ └─┬ better-assert@1.0.2 
│ │ │   └── callsite@1.0.0 
│ │ ├─┬ socket.io-parser@2.2.5 
│ │ │ ├── component-emitter@1.1.2 
│ │ │ └── json3@3.3.2 
│ │ └── to-array@0.1.3 
│ └─┬ socket.io-parser@2.2.6 
│   ├── component-emitter@1.1.2 
│   └── json3@3.3.2 
├─┬ swig@1.4.2 
│ └─┬ uglify-js@2.4.24 
│   ├── async@0.2.10 
│   ├── source-map@0.1.34 
│   ├── uglify-to-browserify@1.0.2 
│   └─┬ yargs@3.5.4 
│     ├── camelcase@1.2.1 
│     ├── decamelize@1.1.2 
│     ├── window-size@0.1.0 
│     └── wordwrap@0.0.2 
└── validator@3.43.0 
 Failed exitCode=-4058, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\5.3.0\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.5.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

I haven't changed anything, so this is the default deploy.cmd for Azure, but just in case it matters, its below:

```
@if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: Version: 1.0.6
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)
goto Deployment

:: Utility Functions
:: -----------------

:SelectNodeVersion

IF DEFINED KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD (
  :: The following are done only on Windows Azure Websites environment
  call %KUDU_SELECT_NODE_VERSION_CMD% "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NODE_EXE=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__nodeVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp" (
    SET /p NPM_JS_PATH=<"%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%\__npmVersion.tmp"
    IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  )

  IF NOT DEFINED NODE_EXE (
    SET NODE_EXE=node
  )

  SET NPM_CMD="!NODE_EXE!" "!NPM_JS_PATH!"
) ELSE (
  SET NPM_CMD=npm
  SET NODE_EXE=node
)

goto :EOF

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

:Deployment
echo Handling node.js deployment.

:: 1. KuduSync
IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
  call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
)

:: 2. Select node version
call :SelectNodeVersion

:: 3. Install npm packages
IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
  pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%"
  call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install --production
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
  popd
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: Post deployment stub
IF DEFINED POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION call "%POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION%"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

Thanks for your help! I've been trying to debug for the last 2 hrs with no progress :-P.

Per Request the current package.json:

```
{
  "name": "TallyCTF",
  "description": "CTF Scoreboard & Event Management Tool.",
  "author" : "Cyber Ninjas",
  "version": "0.4.2",
  "meanjs-version": "0.4.2",
  "private": false,
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/CyberNinjas/TallyCTF.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "5.3.0",
    "npm": "3.5.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "grunt test",
    "postinstall": "bower install --config.interactive=false"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "acl": "~0.4.4",
    "async": "^1.3.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.13.1",
    "bower": "^1.4.1",
    "cfenv": "~1.0.0",
    "chalk": "^1.1.0",
    "compression": "^1.5.0",
    "connect-flash": "~0.1.1",
    "connect-mongo": "~0.8.1",
    "consolidate": "~0.13.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.2",
    "crypto": "0.0.3",
    "express": "^4.13.1",
    "express-session": "^1.11.3",
    "file-stream-rotator": "~0.0.6",
    "forever": "~0.14.2",
    "generate-password": "^1.1.1",
    "glob": "^5.0.13",
    "grunt": "0.4.5",
    "grunt-cli": "~0.1.13",
    "helmet": "~0.9.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.3.4",
    "lodash": "^3.10.0",
    "method-override": "^2.3.3",
    "mocha": "~1.20.0",
    "mongoose": "~4.2.3",
    "morgan": "^1.6.1",
    "multer": "~1.0.5",
    "nodemailer": "^1.4.0",
    "owasp-password-strength-test": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "~0.2.2",
    "passport-facebook": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-github": "~0.1.5",
    "passport-google-oauth": "~0.2.0",
    "passport-linkedin": "~0.1.3",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-paypal-openidconnect": "^0.1.1",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.2",
    "phantomjs": ">=1.9.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.3.0",
    "socket.io": "^1.3.7",
    "swig": "^1.4.2",
    "validator": "^3.41.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "coveralls": "^2.11.4",
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "^1.7.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.3.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-csslint": "~0.1.5",
    "gulp-cssmin": "~0.1.7",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.11.2",
    "gulp-less": "^3.0.3",
    "gulp-livereload": "^3.8.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.0.0-rc.1",
    "gulp-mocha": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-nodemon": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.3",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.6",
    "istanbul": "~0.4.1",
    "karma": "~0.13.15",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.4.2",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.6",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^3.2.0",
    "mock-fs": "~3.4.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.1",
    "should": "^7.0.1",
    "supertest": "^1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you deploy your app via GIT repository or whatever other methods? 
And could you provide your `package.json`, which will be a great helpful for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I'm deploying my app via GitHub Git repo, but I've had similar problems deploying from Visual Studio.com . The entire project is public if you want to look at any of it:
https://github.com/CyberNinjas/TallyCTF . I've been auto-deplying the "develop" branch most recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, it took a lot of digging into, some hunches, and some testing, but I finally got this working. The error was NOT intuitive at all.

What I did to troubleshoot:

1. Downloaded the default MEANJS app and attempted to run it. Even though my app seemed to have no problems with node-sass, this deployment had for some reason.
2. Researched node-sass and noticed it had issues with specific versions of the C++ Runtime. As a result I thought, "Hey maybe the C++ Runtime is a mismatch?"
3. Found Azure Documentation on Kudo which talks about how the environment is setup and mentions the variable MSBUILD_PATH (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-hooks).
4. Googled MSBUILD_PATH and ran into a bunch of bugs related to what it is set to for various Azure websites. This lead me to a thread (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1659).
5. Within the "Configure" tab of my application within manage.windowsazure.com I set the environmental variable MSBUILD_PATH to: 
   `%ProgramFiles(x86)%\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe`
6. From the "Deployment" tab I re-synced my app to trigger a redeploy.
7. Got a new error about failing because Kerberos was missing, added this dependency and re-synced.

   npm install kerberos -save
8. My app deployed successfully.

The following threads were also useful as they relate to Node and specifically MEANJS deployment on Node:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meanjs/LrHmE43RSvA
http://shellmonger.com/2015/08/29/continuous-deployment-nodejs-and-microsoft-azure/

Answer (score 1):

My guess is related to nodejs version. from log you paste it was using node 5.3.0

`npm ERR! argv "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\5.3.0\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.5.1\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"`

can you check locally what node version is on your machine?

if version is different. You can either target to a specific node version by define "engine" property in package.json file or define an Application Settings thru Azure Portal (https://portal.azure.com), your site --> all settings --> Application Settings --> App settings

key: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION, value : {version}

Update 2016-01-09:

i feel like these two folders might be the cause of the issue

D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules.staging\wrappy-e5193d35318260dc6219dca3e7bd3562

D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\bower\node_modules\update-notifier\node_modules\latest-version\node_modules\package-json\node_modules\got\node_modules\duplexify\node_modules\end-of-stream\node_modules\once\node_modules\wrappy

can you check if they contains files that the max length of the file path is greater than 256? if so, it is hitting the Widows File API max length issue.

walk around: try to use a newer version of passportjs, hope it won`t have that many nested dependency, otherwise, there is no way out :(
(since you mention you app was running fine before, try to go back to any one of the old deployment, from log you should see what version you use there and try to set to same version for all packages)

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that and actually tried that last night right after I posted it. I still get the same errors. I'm using Node 4.2.4 in both now and have the same results.

Comment: I'm sorry, but nothing you posted has been useful in helping me resolve this and it doesn't appear to be the issue.